# Are my Unit Tests any good?

Tags: php, unit-testing

This is the first time I have written Unit Tests. I am testing code that I have already written and would like to move to TDD once I have managed to get units written for everything that is already in my application.

Just wanted to be sure that the tests that I have written look good, or if there is a different approach I should be taken. These are for CakePHP 2.0

```
<?php
App::uses('Player', 'Model');

class PlayerTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
public $fixtures = array('app.player', 'app.club', 'app.position', 'app.stat', 'app.selection', 'app.period', 'app.league', 'app.draft', 'app.team');

public function setup() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->Player = ClassRegistry::init('Player');
}

/**
 * testGetPlayers method
 *
 * @return void
 */ 
function testGetPlayers() {

    //Specific Player, All Stats, No Position Exclusion 
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(11, 'all', null);
    $expected = array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 11, 'name' => 'Forward 2', 'status' => 'doubtful', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '2', 'position_id' => '4'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Club 2', 'abbreviation' => 'clb2'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forward', 'abbreviation' => 'fw', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 3, 'need' => 2, 'db_abbr' => 'fw'),
            'Stat' => array (
                array ('id' => 11, 'rank' => 11, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '11', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1'),
                array ('id' => 23, 'rank' => 11, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '11', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '2')
            )
    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);    

    //Specific Player, No Stats, No Position Exclusion
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(10, false, null);       
    $expected = array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 10, 'name' => 'Forward 1', 'status' => 'available', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '1', 'position_id' => '4'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Club 1', 'abbreviation' => 'clb1'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forward', 'abbreviation' => 'fw', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 3, 'need' => 2, 'db_abbr' => 'fw')
    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);    

    //No Specific Player, No Stats, Position Exclusion (Array)
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(null, false, array('def', 'mid', 'fw'));        
    $expected = array(
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper 1', 'status' => 'available', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '1', 'position_id' => '1'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Club 1', 'abbreviation' => 'clb1'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper', 'abbreviation' => 'gk', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 1, 'need' => 1, 'db_abbr' => 'gk')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper 2', 'status' => 'doubtful', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '2', 'position_id' => '1'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Club 2', 'abbreviation' => 'clb2'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper', 'abbreviation' => 'gk', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 1, 'need' => 1, 'db_abbr' => 'gk')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper 3', 'status' => 'unavailable', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '3', 'position_id' => '1'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Club 3', 'abbreviation' => 'clb3'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper', 'abbreviation' => 'gk', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 1, 'need' => 1, 'db_abbr' => 'gk')
            )
    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);    

    //No Specific Player, Default Stats, Position Exclusion (String)
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(null, true, 'gk');      
    $expected = array(
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Defender 1', 'status' => 'available', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '1', 'position_id' => '2'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Club 1', 'abbreviation' => 'clb1'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Defender', 'abbreviation' => 'def', 'min' => 3, 'max' => 5, 'need' => 4, 'db_abbr' => 'def'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 4, 'rank' => 4, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '4', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 5, 'name' => 'Defender 2', 'status' => 'doubtful', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '2', 'position_id' => '2'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Club 2', 'abbreviation' => 'clb2'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Defender', 'abbreviation' => 'def', 'min' => 3, 'max' => 5, 'need' => 4, 'db_abbr' => 'def'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 5, 'rank' => 5, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '5', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 6, 'name' => 'Defender 3', 'status' => 'unavailable', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '3', 'position_id' => '2'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Club 3', 'abbreviation' => 'clb3'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Defender', 'abbreviation' => 'def', 'min' => 3, 'max' => 5, 'need' => 4, 'db_abbr' => 'def'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 6, 'rank' => 6, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '6', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 7, 'name' => 'Midfielder 1', 'status' => 'available', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '1', 'position_id' => '3'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Club 1', 'abbreviation' => 'clb1'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Midfielder', 'abbreviation' => 'mid', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 5, 'need' => 4, 'db_abbr' => 'mid'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 7, 'rank' => 7, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '7', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 8, 'name' => 'Midfielder 2', 'status' => 'doubtful', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '2', 'position_id' => '3'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Club 2', 'abbreviation' => 'clb2'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Midfielder', 'abbreviation' => 'mid', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 5, 'need' => 4, 'db_abbr' => 'mid'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 8, 'rank' => 8, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '8', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 9, 'name' => 'Midfielder 3', 'status' => 'unavailable', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '3', 'position_id' => '3'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Club 3', 'abbreviation' => 'clb3'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Midfielder', 'abbreviation' => 'mid', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 5, 'need' => 4, 'db_abbr' => 'mid'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 9, 'rank' => 9, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '9', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 10, 'name' => 'Forward 1', 'status' => 'available', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '1', 'position_id' => '4'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Club 1', 'abbreviation' => 'clb1'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forward', 'abbreviation' => 'fw', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 3, 'need' => 2, 'db_abbr' => 'fw'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 10, 'rank' => 10, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '10', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 11, 'name' => 'Forward 2', 'status' => 'doubtful', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '2', 'position_id' => '4'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Club 2', 'abbreviation' => 'clb2'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forward', 'abbreviation' => 'fw', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 3, 'need' => 2, 'db_abbr' => 'fw'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 11, 'rank' => 11, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '11', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            ),
        array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 12, 'name' => 'Forward 3', 'status' => 'unavailable', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '3', 'position_id' => '4'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Club 3', 'abbreviation' => 'clb3'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forward', 'abbreviation' => 'fw', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 3, 'need' => 2, 'db_abbr' => 'fw'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 12, 'rank' => 12, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '12', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
            )
    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);    

    //Specific Player, Default Stats, No Position Exclusion
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(10, true, null);        
    $expected = array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 10, 'name' => 'Forward 1', 'status' => 'available', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '1', 'position_id' => '4'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Club 1', 'abbreviation' => 'clb1'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forward', 'abbreviation' => 'fw', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 3, 'need' => 2, 'db_abbr' => 'fw'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 10, 'rank' => 10, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '10', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1')
    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);    

    //Specific Player, Specific Stats, No Position Exclusion
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(10, 2, null);       
    $expected = array(
            'Player' => array ('id' => 10, 'name' => 'Forward 1', 'status' => 'available', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '1', 'position_id' => '4'),
            'Club' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Club 1', 'abbreviation' => 'clb1'),
            'Position' => array ('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forward', 'abbreviation' => 'fw', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 3, 'need' => 2, 'db_abbr' => 'fw'),
            'Stat' => array ('id' => 22, 'rank' => 10, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '10', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '2')
    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);

    //Player That Doesn't Exist
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(999999, true, null);
    $this->assertFalse($result);        

    //Stats That Don't Exist
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(null, 9999999, null);
    $this->assertFalse($result);    

    //Filter All Positions
    $result = $this->Player->GetPlayers(null, 9999999, array('gk', 'def', 'mid', 'fw'));
    $this->assertFalse($result);

}

//GetAvailablePlayers($league_id = null, $get_stats = true, $top_ranked_only = false, $exclude_positions = null) {  

function testGetAvailablePlayers() {

    //Get The Top Ranked Available Player with Stats
    $result = $this->Player->GetAvailablePlayers(1, null, true, null);
    $expected = array(
        'Player' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper 2', 'status' => 'doubtful', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '2', 'position_id' => '1'),
        'Club' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Club 2', 'abbreviation' => 'clb2'),
        'Position' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper', 'abbreviation' => 'gk', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 1, 'need' => 1, 'db_abbr' => 'gk'),
        'Stat' => array ('id' => 2, 'rank' => 2, 'goals' => 0, 'saves' => 0, 'penaltysaves' => 0, 'assists' => 0, 'cleansheet' => 0, 'redcard' => 0, 'yellowcard' => 0, 'foulsconc' => 0, 'foulswon' => 0, 'tackleslost' => 0, 'tackleswon' => 0, 'shotontarget' => 0, 'totalshot' => 0, 'appearances' => 0, 'attcreated' => 0, 'totalpasses' => 0, 'accpasses' => 0, 'minutesplayed' => 0, 'conceded' => 0, 'player_id' => '2', 'team_id' => 0, 'period_id' => '1'),
        'Selection' => array ('id' => '', 'drafted' => '', 'locked' => '', 'position_id' => '', 'league_id' => '', 'team_id' => '', 'player_id' => '', 'period_id' => '')
    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);

    //Get All Available Players with No Stats Filtered by Position
    $result = $this->Player->GetAvailablePlayers(1, false, null, array('def', 'mid', 'fw'));
    $expected = array(
        array( 
        'Player' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper 2', 'status' => 'doubtful', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '2', 'position_id' => '1'),
        'Club' => array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Club 2', 'abbreviation' => 'clb2'),
        'Position' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper', 'abbreviation' => 'gk', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 1, 'need' => 1, 'db_abbr' => 'gk'),
        'Selection' => array ('id' => '', 'drafted' => '', 'locked' => '', 'position_id' => '', 'league_id' => '', 'team_id' => '', 'player_id' => '', 'period_id' => '')
        ), 
        array( 
        'Player' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper 3', 'status' => 'unavailable', 'note' => '', 'club_id' => '3', 'position_id' => '1'),
        'Club' => array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Club 3', 'abbreviation' => 'clb3'),
        'Position' => array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Goalkeeper', 'abbreviation' => 'gk', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 1, 'need' => 1, 'db_abbr' => 'gk'),
        'Selection' => array ('id' => '', 'drafted' => '', 'locked' => '', 'position_id' => '', 'league_id' => '', 'team_id' => '', 'player_id' => '', 'period_id' => '')
        ), 
    );
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);

    //Test With League That Doesn't Exist
    $result = $this->Player->GetAvailablePlayers(5);
    $this->assertFalse($result);

}

function testIsAvailable() { 
    $result = $this->Player->IsAvailable(1, 1);
    $this->assertFalse($result);

    $result = $this->Player->IsAvailable(2, 1);
    $this->assertTrue($result); 

    $result = $this->Player->IsAvailable(1, 999999);
    $this->assertFalse($result);        
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$this->Player->GetPlayers(11, 'all', null);` get its data from in this test?

Comment: It's a method in my Player model.

Comment: I can see that what I mean is where does that method get it's data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'd create a distinct method for every `assertEquals()` call. It helps [defect localization](http://xunitpatterns.com/Goals%20of%20Test%20Automation.html#Defect%20Localization). If the first `assert` throws an error you'll have no idea that the 2nd, 3rd and the others are OK or not. Having only one `assert` call per test method is a good practice. The comments should be the name of these methods. (Comment usually is a code smell.)

The `$expected` arrays are rather complicated. If the `Player` class get a new field (e.g. nickname) you probably have to modify all of your tests which could be a huge pain. I suggest using [custom assert methods](http://xunitpatterns.com/Custom%20Assertion.html). For example, instead of

```
//Get All Available Players with No Stats Filtered by Position
$result = $this->Player->GetAvailablePlayers(1, false, null, array('def', 'mid', 'fw'));
$expected = array(...)
$this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
```

try

```
function testGetAllAvailablePlayersWithNoStatsFilteredByPosition() {
    $result = $this->Player->GetAvailablePlayers(1, false, null, 
        array('def', 'mid', 'fw'));
    $this->assertPlayerCount("playerCount", 2, $result);
    $this->assertPlayerIdEquals("player id 1", 2, $result[0]);
    $this->assertPlayerIdEquals("player id 2", 3, $result[1]);
}
```

(Of course you have write the `assertPlayerCount` and `assertPlayerIdEquals` methods. The first string parameter is an [assertion message](http://xunitpatterns.com/Assertion%20Message.html). It's useful if you have more than one `assert` call in one test method.)

In this test class you use [Shared Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Shared%20Fixture.html). If it's possible try using fresh fixture with [Inline Setup](http://xunitpatterns.com/Inline%20Setup.html). From 
[Test Automation Strategy, The Three Major Fixture Strategies](http://xunitpatterns.com/TestStrategy.html#The%20Three%20Major%20Fixture%20Strategies):

> This Shared Fixture strategy is often used to improve the execution
>   speed of tests that use a Persistent Fresh Fixture but it comes with a
>   fair amount of baggage. These test require the use of one of the
>   fixture construction and tear down triggering patterns. They also
>   involve tests that interact with each other, whether by design or
>   consequence, and this often leads to Erratic Tests (page X) and High
>   Test Maintenance Costs.

(The cited text has links, check them.)

If you have enough time it's worth reading the whole [XUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/) book. Reading just the Part I (and Part II.) is also beneficial.

(Please note that I haven't written any PHP code in last few years, so the sample codes probably don't compile etc.)

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. Will have a read through everything and hopefully tidy everything up. One other question - if you don't mind, some of my save functions update various fields in the DB. Should I test them using a custom assert function too - to ensure that the data in the DB is as expected.

Comment: You are welcome :) Yes, you should. Just keep it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Less redundancy in a the code -> easier to maintain. Custom assert methods helps to avoid redundant test code (and increase test readability etc.).

Comment: Anyway, testing with database sounds like an integration test not an unit test. In tests try mocking the database or use in-memory databases to avoid the possibility of [interacting tests](http://xunitpatterns.com/Erratic%20Test.html#Interacting%20Tests). 

(If a test hasn't cleaned the database the next test could fail because of the remained records in the database. Life is easier with a fresh fixture.) (Furthermore, it's much faster of course.)